# How to allow AWS Cognito configuration with Username & Email login using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I would like to create Cognito (using CLOUDFORMATION) which allow login with Username & Email, I have gone through   [AWS user pool documents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html) and also follow [Cognito Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html), But didn't find any solution.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check here the cloudformation for a Userpool: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-emailconfiguration)

About your question:

Use "AliasAttributes" with an array with the string "email", "preferred_username"

yaml:

AliasAttributes:

- email
- preferred_username

json:

"AliasAttributes": ["email", "preferred_username"]

**edit:**  AliasAttributes instead of UsernameAttributes

Comment: The problem with UsernameAttributes is, when adding email then Cognito configure for email  only instead of username & Email when adding email.

Comment: Ah, ok. So you are looking for AliasAttributes. That should do the trick.

"AliasAttributes":  ["email", "preferred_username"]
or:

AliasAttributes:
    - email
    - preferred_username

Comment: can we use email & preferred_username for login if we added into AliasAttributes .?